# TinyMCE Editor (3.x) altering format when pasting from Word 2015

Tags: coldfusion, tinymce

When I copy the contents of a properly formatted word document, meaning it has H1 tags, 3 paragraphs, a URL link, and an email link, some bolded and some italicized words - basically a very basic document, the formatting isn't retained. Below is my init file.

```
    tinyMCE.init({
    // General options
    mode : "exact",
    elements : "content",
    theme: "advanced",
    //plugins : "safari,pagebreak,advhr,advimage,advlink,iespell,insertdatetime,preview,paste,fullscreen",
    plugins : "pagebreak,style,advlink,iespell,insertdatetime,preview,print,contextmenu,paste,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,inlinepopups",
    plugin_preview_width : "500",
    plugin_preview_height : "600",
    // Theme options
    theme_advanced_buttons1:"cut,copy,paste,pasteword,|,undo,redo,|,bold,italic,underline,|,forecolor,backcolor|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,|,bullist,numlist,|fullscreen,code,iespell,imageButton,preview",
    theme_advanced_disable : "help,removeformat,sub,sup,anchor,link,unlink,image,|,insertdate,inserttime,advhr,print",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
    paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste: false,
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "center",
    valid_elements : "*[*]",
    convert_urls:true,
    cleanup : false          
});
```

When I run the following console commands, I do see the "html" code IS there. Also, when I click on the HTML icon in the toolbar, I see the HTML code there, too (though all the H1 tags are removed except for the first one).

```
// Get the HTML contents of the currently active editor
console.debug(tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent());

// Get the raw contents of the currently active editor
tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent({format : 'raw'});

// Get content of a specific editor:
tinyMCE.get('content').getContent()
```

When I click the submit button, all I have on my action page is a simple cfdump and there, it is just plain text and a giant since paragraph. There are no P tags, not H1 tags, just plain text.

```
<cfdump var="#form.content#">
<cfoutput>
    #form.content#
    <textarea>#form.content#</textarea>
</cfoutput>
```

Just for grins, on the action page, I inserted the form.content into my MSSQL database with a datatype of nvarchar(2000) just to see if maybe the browser was playing games and the database only shows plain text, too. Here is another abnormality is that when I run my test page in Chrome, only plain text is saved. When I run the test page in FireFox, the Microsoft XML data is saved.

I only need one browser to work. Can someone provide any guidance on this?

Comment: http://archive.tinymce.com/tryit/3_x/full.php - this sample shows the html tags in the dump. The only difference is the dump is a PHP but that shouldn't matter, right?

Comment: All I can think is that the editor is stripping out the HTML in order to avoid Cross Site Scripting attacks. TimyMCE isn't an HTML editor, it's a text editor. If you want to enter HTML into it, you should probably open the HTML view via that icon and paste the HTML in there.

Comment: The X Site Scripting is definitely something I hadn't considered. In terms of HTML editor vs Text editor, you are supposed to be able to pass in HTML code though (e.g. from a database field) and it'll convert it to the Text Editor equivalent. I understand the limitations but for the content being passed in should be well withing its capabilities.

As for the X-Scripting, do you know by chance what the attribute is to disabled that safety feature?

Comment: I've no idea, don't use that editor, but others work similarly. Odds are, you can't bypass that filtering.

Comment: With the others you have used, did you see this behavior? If not, which one(s) did you use? I'm not married to TinyMCE.

Comment: I've used CKEditor and others that no longer exist. I think the problem you're having is that these are Rich Text Editors, not HTML editors. If you had formatted your text in Word, not as HTML, the editor would probably convert the Word markup to HTML. As for bypassing the XSS filters, odds are, you can't. They're there for a reason and you'd be opening up a major security hole if you managed to turn it off. Not sure what else you can try but to paste in the plain text and format it in the editor.

Comment: I've done some more research into the XSS items and I do believe it would be better to leave that in place. I'll see if I can find another way to accomplish this task. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gotta love spaghetti code.

There was some logic that I missed that was doing a check for browsers that I missed so the issue was really with fckeditor and not tinymce.

**/Start Snippet from: http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/FCK-Link-picker-errors-FF-3**

I got the same problem with FCK 2.3.2. The best solution is to change function CreateLink in fckeditorcode_gecko.js:
Old code I had:

`FCK.CreateLink=function(A){FCK.ExecuteNamedCommand('Unlink');if (A.length>0){var B='javascript:void(0);/*'+(new Date().getTime())+'*/';FCK.ExecuteNamedCommand('CreateLink',B);var C=document.evaluate("//a[@href='"+B+"']",this.EditorDocument.body,null,9,null).singleNodeValue;if (C){C.href=A;return C;}}};`

New code:

`FCK.CreateLink=function(A){FCK.ExecuteNamedCommand('Unlink');if (A.length>0){var B='javascript:void(0);/*'+(new Date().getTime())+'*/';FCK.ExecuteNamedCommand('CreateLink',B);var C=this.EditorDocument.evaluate("//a[@href='"+B+"']",this.EditorDocument.body,null,9,null).singleNodeValue;if (C){C.href=A;return C;}}};`

In fact, I only replaced document.evaluate with this.EditorDocument.evaluate

**/end snippet**